# log-sum-exp trick for signed/complex numbers

Tags: numerics, stability, floating-point, precision

I need to evaluate a sum of values that are on many different orders of magnitude in scale but might be signed.  I’ve had great luck with the [“log-sum-exp” trick](https://www.xarg.org/2016/06/the-log-sum-exp-trick-in-machine-learning/) for an unsigned version of my problem, so I’m hoping to apply this to the signed values.

Suppose $z,z’\in\mathbb C$ are stored using separate real and imaginary parts in double precision.  We wish to compute $w:=\log(e^z + e^{z’})$.   Here I’m not concerned about which branch of log we get back—at the end of the day only $e^w$ matters, the logs are just for numerical stability.

For any $a\in\mathbb C$, by an identical argument to the log-sum-exp trick we know
$$W=a+\log(e^{z-a}+ e^{z’-a}),$$
again up to branch of log.

Is there a good “policy” for choosing $a$ to promote numerical stability, similar to the max suggested for the real valued log-sum-exp trick?

Comment: Tiny update: I guess the branch issue is irrelevant since I’m storing complex numbers in Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Have you thought about the Kahan summation algorithm?

Comment: Unfortunately Kahan summation won't be enough -- my computation involves factorials so it needs to be on log scale.

Comment: Just passing by and I am not an expert, but I would imagine that one needs to use `log1p` here to get some stability for inputs of wildly different size.

Comment: Yes, probably a good idea for log-sum-exp generically as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After thinking about this some more, I can answer this one myself!

I don't think the complex plane makes the log-sum-exp trick appreciably different, at least in Cartesian coordinates.  In particular, if $z=u+iv$ then $e^z=e^{u+iv}=e^u (\cos v + i\sin v).$  Notice the $v$ part has magnitude 1 by construction, so overflow or underflow is principally caused by $u$.

Hence, a reasonable choice is to take $a = \max( \mathrm{real}(z), \mathrm{real}(z') ).$

Comment: For numerical reasons it's better is to use the logp1 function. To that end choose $a = \mathrm{argmax}_{u\in\{z,z'\}} \mathrm{Re}[u]$. In this case, $w = a + \log \left(e^{z-a} + e^{z'-a}\right) = a + \log\left(1 + e^{z-z'}\right)$ if $\mathrm{Re}[z']>\mathrm{Re}[z]$ else $w=a + \log\left(1 + e^{z'-z}\right)$.